AuthJS extend profile info return from Google
I'm trying to use auth.js with auth0 authentication with Google. I would like the object that returns as User to contain additional information such as gender, date of birth and address. I added the scopes to the Google API console but it keeps returning the same object with: iss, azp, aud, sub,  email,  email_verified,  at_hash,  name,  picture,  given_name, family_name, iat, exp.
How can I return additional information?
